# Search a string from inbutbox in a different table with dlookup and return the value to a MsgBox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I try to find the value from a table which the user search by a inputbox. Afterwards, the value should be display in a MsgBox.

Tablename: Names

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 10001 | Adam |
| 10002 | Eva |

My current code:

```
Private Sub Clientnr_GotFocus()
    DoCmd.RefreshRecord
    
    Dim sr As String

    sr = InputBox("Enter a number:", "Search number")
    X = DLookup("Column B", "Names", "Column A =" & sr)
    MsgBox X, vbOKOnly
    
End Sub
```

I also tried the following code:

```
Private Sub Clientnr_GotFocus()
    DoCmd.RefreshRecord
    
    Dim sr As String

    sr = 10001
    X = DLookup("Column B", "Names", "Column A =" & sr)
    MsgBox X, vbOKOnly
    
End Sub
```

I always get an error message because the value is NULL.

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in the field names, and use *Nz* to avoid a *Null* as result, thus:

```vb
Private Sub Kundennr_GotFocus()

    Dim sr As String

    DoCmd.RefreshRecord
    
    sr = InputBox("Bitte Kundennummer eingeben:", "Kundennummer suchen")
    X = Nz(DLookup("[Column B]", "Names", "[Column A] = " & sr),"") ' null to ""
    MsgBox X, vbOKOnly
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The "DoCmd.RefreshRecord" was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

You have an extra opening bracket, Both！

X = `(`DLookup("Column B", "Names", "Column A =" & sr) ⇒

```
X = DLookup("Column B", "Names", "Column A =""" & sr & """")
```

or use StrComp function:

```
X = DLookup("Column B", "Names", "strcomp(Column A,""" & sr & """)=0")
```

ps. Adding square brackets is also right, like *Gustav*'s answer.